# Attempting to only copy files that have changed within the last day while maintaining folder structure

Tags: files, scripting, find, cp

I'm attempting to find and copy files that have been modified within the last day. While doing that I'm trying maintain folder structures under `dir1`. There are many subdirectories under `dir1` and data files within those.

Below is what I cobbled together so far but apparently `mtime` is not updated on directories if the contents of a file is updated. Also I believe this cp command will copy all of the files in a directory rather than just those that have changed.

```bsh
find /NAS/data/dir1 -type d -mtime -1 -exec cp -at /mnt/databackup/dir1 {} +
```

If I used `-type f` it would not retain the folder structure.

Comment: Why "within the last day"?  Is this a script you will run daily?  So if you run it Monday, it should catch files changed within the last 24 hours, but ignore files that were changed say, on Saturday?  Or do you **really** want a script that finds and copies *all* files that have been changed since the last time the script was run?  Putting that another way, what if you forget to run the script one day?  Should the next run of the script copy the files that got missed because of the day you forgot to run it?  Is `rsync` the tool you're really looking for?

Comment: I would also guess `rsync` is the simpler and more robust solution here. And I wouldn't rely on `mtime` (and file size) and use option `--checksum` even if it takes longer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find ... -type f`, with a bash for-loop. In the loop, a combination of `mkdir -p` and `dirname` would let you recreate the folder structure, before simply copying each file with cp.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

dirA="/NAS/data/dir1/"
dirB="/mnt/databackup/dir1/"
while read -r file
do
    relative="${file##"$dirA"}"
    newfile="$dirB$relative"
    echo mkdir -p "$(dirname "$file")"
    echo cp -at "$file" "$newfile"
done < <(find "$dirA" -type f -mtime -1)
```

- `read` is a bash builtin. It is classically used with `-r` to avoid some edge-case problems. It reads one line (at a time) from it's `stdin`. Here, that `stdin` is the output of `find`.
- `${var##string-to-remove}` is a form of [parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)
- `newfile="$dirB$relative"`. This is a classical bash concatenation
- `$()`. This bash construct is called [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html)
- `mkdir -p` create a directory and all it's ancestors as needed
- `cmd < file` this is a classic redirection
- `<(cmd)` this is called [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html). It substitute a filename as handle to the stdin [`>()`] or stdout [`<()`] of a command.

You can [use explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=dirA%3D%22%2FNAS%2Fdata%2Fdir1%2F%22%3B%20dirB%3D%22%2Fmnt%2Fdatabackup%2Fdir1%2F%22%3B%20while%20read%20-r%20file%3B%20do%20relative%3D%22%24%7Bfile%23%23%22%24dirA%22%7D%22%3B%20newfile%3D%22%24dirB%24relative%22%3B%20mkdir%20-p%20%22%24(dirname%20%22%24file%22)%22%3B%20cp%20-at%20%22%24file%22%20%22%24newfile%22%3B%20done%20%3C%20%3C(find%20%22%24dirA%22%20-type%20f%20-mtime%20-1)) to get more detailed explanations.

Comment: It would be safer to execute the loop from within `find` with e.g. `find ... -exec sh -c 'for file do ...; done' sh {} +`.